# react better solution for custom hooks when using setInterval and stale closures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures

```
const useCounterInterval = (
  startAt = 0,
  countingStep = 1,
  countingTime = 1000
) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(startAt);
  const [timerId, setTimerId] = useState(null);

  const scheduleCounting = useCallback(() => {
    if (timerId !== null) return;
    setTimerId(
      setInterval(() => {
        setCounter(counter => counter + countingStep);
      }, countingTime)
    );
  }, [timerId, countingStep, countingTime]);

  const clearSchedule = useCallback(() => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    setTimerId(null);
  }, [timerId]);

  const stopCounting = useCallback(() => {
    clearSchedule();
  }, [clearSchedule]);

  const resetCounting = useCallback(() => {
    clearSchedule();
    setCounter(0);
  }, [clearSchedule]);

  useEffect(() => {
    scheduleCounting();
    // scheduleCounting();
    // clearSchedule();
  }, []);

  return [counter, scheduleCounting, stopCounting, resetCounting];
};
```

Tried real hard to insert running code snippets for this code but didn't work as I thought sorry for that.

I created this custom hook to get a grasp of what hooks are.

It works but there are logical issues.

1. cannot 'clearInterval()' before second render ***(stopCounting())***
2. Logically, can set multiple counting schedules by code ***(scheduleCounting())***
3. maybe hook design is wrong at first place?

For the first issue, I cannot clear the very first scheduled timer set in motion by *useEffect()* before the second render where *timerId* is set with new value. Because obviously, *stopCounting()* have closure to *timerId* where the value is null.
And when the timing is right, I can notice by clicking on a button (depends on which event *stopCounter()* is bounded). I don't have a clue on how to solve this issue for now. I can just remove *scheduleCounting()* from *useEffect()* but that's not an option I wanna know if there's a way to solve this.

Second, I can set multiple counting schedule by calling *scheduleCounting()* in *useEffect()*. Come to think of it, I might call *scheduleCounting()* multiple times by clicking on a button really fast but seems like I can't, unlike calling *stopCounting()* before second render. But the logic is that I can do that right?

So, the problem here was that *scheduleCounting()* had closure to the same *timerId* value which is null

```
const scheduleCounting = useCallback(() => {
if (timerId !== null) return; // bypassing this line of code
```

The solution here was to make use of *useRef()*. Instead of checking if *timerId* is null whose value may vary depending on the creation time of functions referencing it. I can simply

```
const schedulerState = useRef(false)
if (schedulerState.current === true) return;
```

It made sure every *scheduleCounting()* was referencing the same latest value at any time. But using a flag(ref, state) make code less readable. I wanna keep myself away from using flags. I wonder maybe there's another ***reactive*** way of dealing with this problem?

I don't know where I'm getting wrong. Can't stop thinking I might go down the wrong road if I don't get it right. Need some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From design point of view, I'd not keep `timerId` in state. Instead I'd have state `isCounting`:

```
const useCounterInterval = (
  startAt = 0,
  countingStep = 1,
  countingTime = 1000
) => {
  const [isCounting, setIsCounting] = useState(false);
  const [currentTick, setTick] = useState(0);
  
  const startCounting = useCallback(() => { setIsCounting(true); }, []);
  const stopCounting = useCallback(() => { setIsCounting(false); }, []);
  const resetCounting = useCallback(() => { setTick(0); }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    resetCounting();
    if (isCounting) {
      const timerId = setInterval(() => {
        setTick(i => i + 1);
      }, countingTime);

      return () => { clearInterval(timerId); };
    }
  }, [isCounting, resetCounting, countingTime, startAt, countingStep]);

  return [
    currentTick * countingStep + startAt, 
    startCounting, 
    stopCounting, 
    resetCounting,
    isCounting
  ];
};
```

It's easier not to store `timerId` but keep it in `useEffect`'s closure. As well as it's better to return whether counting is happening(by returning `isCounting`).

Comment: That was really clean and clear. I thought 'states' as more of variables that allow us to comfortably re-render components. The timerId isn't exactly a state I should care about thus, using it in closure makes more sense. Having isCounting state is very intuitive in reactive aspect I guess. As well as the code got a lot leaner by removing duplication in start, stop, reset function. And returning counter value in a format of calculation instead of static value seems more flexible though nothing changed. Thank you